# Can someone tell me what this means, please?

Tags: translation

Good day.
I would like to know what this character means. Can you help me translate it? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: I've read a news last week that there's a Vietnamese guy who doesn't know Chinese but tatoo fake Chinese characters on his customers. This character means happiness as Henry Ho answered. Just never presume an asian-looking guy know Chinese.

Answer (score 4):

“歓” (http://www.zdic.net/z/1c/zy/6B53.htm)

An ancient form of "歡", meaning happy and joy.

(never tattoo something you don't know .....)